# Grep data from file in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to process a html page and identify the hyper links present in the page. I am successful if the code is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/test.html">
```

I used a simple regex to identify the data which is between double quotes and that starts with `/` and I got all the liks which are of this type.

But I am not able to understand how to get the links if the script is like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test/test.html">
```

because I canot use the same old regex or if I try to use the regex gets data which is in double quotes then I will get `"text/javascript"` also in the output which is not required. Can I use seek() to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the regex you  have tried so we could modify that ?

Comment: re.compile('"/([^"]*)"')

Comment: would this not compile `text/javascript` ?

Comment: No.Since I used / immediatly after " .

Comment: No i meant in the modified regex.

Comment: re.compile('"/([^"]*)"')  this is original regex and I tried to modify it by just removing / so it looks like re.compile('"([^"]*)"') and this will process both text/javascript and test/test.html

Comment: I think you'll also need to consider tag names like src, href etc. Just a thought..

Comment: Try this: `re.compile('"\/?(([\s]+)\/?)+(\.[\s]+)"')`

Comment: No....It dint work. It returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
regex = re.compile('src="([^"]*)"')
result = regex.match(html)
print result.match(1)
```

Comment: tried this one too It outputs src="test/test.html" I need only test/test.html

Comment: You have brackets inside the quotes, are you pulling out the match instead of the whole thing?

Comment: No I just placed bracket just make sure that I will not get a blank result.